# google maps jar file missing from android sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, google-api

I am writing an android application however I am using the google maps api and when I run my code iI get the following error...

```
C:\android-sdk-windows\add-ons\addon-google_apis_google_inc maps.jar has no source attachment
```

and

```
E/AndroidRuntime(374): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{lbs.tutorial/lbs.tutorial.WhereAmIActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lbs.tutorial.WhereAmIActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/lbs.tutorial-2.apk]
```

sure enough through windows explorer the add-ons folder is empty, cann anyone tell me how to get this jar file?

I have updated the google apis in the sdk and the adt plugin is up to date. Ive triple checked my files but im at a loss.

Thanks for looking

Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're targeting the right platform in your project. For each version of Android you can select the open-source version or the Google version (which has maps etc included).

In Eclipse: Right click on your project properties --> Android --> Select project build target (making sure that you click the Google APIs version).

Comment: Hi Damian, I've already tried this and it doesn't help me I still get the same errors. I've actually got to the maps.jar file now however it still force closes my app and leaves me with the same errors as above.    Thanks for looking though!

Comment: Actually this is a problem with your WhereAmIActivity. Have you declared it properlay (or at all) in your Manifest?

Comment: Yeah its all declared in the manifest, inside my manifest I have the following below my activity tag and above the intent filter tag...

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity android:name=".WhereAmIActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">

Ill keep on going! thanks Damian!

Comment: Course...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="lbs.tutorial"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity android:name=".WhereAmIActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Hope this helps, I'm not any further forward. Really appreciate your help!

Peter
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
</manifest>

Comment: That looks ok to me. Only thing I can suggest is 1) make sure that an app with the same package name does not exist on the phone / emulator. 2) Make sure that your app is not crashing in the onCreate method. 3) Follow some leads in this google search http://goo.gl/PhepG

Comment: Really appreciate you taking time on this Damian. thanks alot!